# Google docs does not preserve the file name when exported

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm trying to export my Google Docs blog post which has the content and the images in it, I uploaded all the images with proper names such as **my-cool-header.png**

Now when I try to export it by any means via the Download, it has changed the names of the images to image.png, image-1.png, and so on.

[image: exported via the Google docs Download]

[image: File name has been changed]

So is there any way we can preserve the names of the images while we export them as Docx files?

Thank you

Comment: Where do you open your docx? I can't seem to find the option to see the image details you've shown above. Not in my chromebook nor windows pc.

Comment: This is ubuntu doc software, just like Ms office in windows, the export with HTML has also name change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. I have not found any reference to check nor confirm the image details on the document aside from the `Image options` that only includes the following:

#### Image Options:

[image: imageOptions]

The Docs doesn't store anything from the image you included aside from the details above thus when opened in another document reader app, that app initializes the images' names into its own default image names (e.g `image.png, image-1.png, etc.`) as they didn't receive any details about it.

If alternative text is an option, you might want to try `Alt text`.

To access `Alt Text`, `right click image` -> `Alt Text`, or `click image` -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

#### Alt Text:

[image: altText]

Try and see if filling up the `Title` and `Description` of the image in Google Docs shows under `Alternative (Text only)` and `Description` details of your image in the app you use to read the exported file.

Comment: Not the alt attribute, I mean the actual image name such as my-image.png

Comment: Sad to say that there is no way to retain the image name since in the first place it isn't saved in the document when an image is inserted that's why I tried recommending the alt text if it is an option. @MZH

Comment: Hi @MZH, if we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved or not.